# Add video to display on product page

Tags: magento-1, product-video

How to add product video at product-page?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create one attribute under admin panel > catalog > attributes > create attribute on the name of video
2. By using , you can get that data

> ```
> <iframe width="100%" height="auto" src="<?php echo $_product-> 
>  getData('video'); ?>" frameborder="1" allowfullscreen></iframe>
> ```

3. You have to use this code at your view.phtml file.